# How to specify KMS VPC endpoint url using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-kms

I have a lambda function running inside my private subnet. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html#vpce-connect), this endpoint needs to be specified under the `endpoint-url` parameter.

This parameter [exists inside the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kms/encrypt.html), however **not** within the [Boto3 implementation of the same function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.encrypt)!

What gives? How do I encrypt from within my VPC using Boto3 (using the default url causes a `EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL` error- even though I already set it as a private DNS as per the docs)?

Comment: Show us your code. And is there any particular reason you're looking to use a specific endpoint url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Boto3 you set the endpoint URL when you create the client, not when you call individual methods on the client.

```
client = boto3.kms("kms", endpoint_url="your_kms_URL")
client.encrypt()
```

Although if this is going to a VPC Interface Endpoint, you might want to review your VPC's DNS settings, and the endpoints Security Group settings, because this should be working out-of-the-box without the need to explicitly specify the endpoint in code.